# Complex $(\mathcal A,\mathcal d)$ splits iff $id_A$ is null homotopic

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Consider $(\mathcal A,\mathcal d)$ is a complex  of $R$-modules and  $\mathcal d=\{d_n,d_n : A_{n+1} \to A_n , n \in \mathbb N \}$ are chain maps.

Show that $(\mathcal A,d)$ splits iff $id_\mathcal A$ is null-homotoic.

An $R$-complex $(\mathcal A,d)$ is said to split if there is family of maps like $s=\{s_n, s_n: A_{n-1} \to A_n , n \in \mathbb N \}$ such that $d_n=d_ns_{n-1}d_n$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ If  $id_\mathcal A \sim 0$ then there are family maps of $s_n$ such that $id_n=d_{n+1}s_n + s_{n-1}d_n$ now by composition $d_n$ we have $d_nid_n=d_nd_{n+1}s_n + d_ns_{n-1}d_n$ and it is equal to $d_n=d_ns_{n-1}d_n$, then complex $(\mathcal A,d)$ is split. But for $(\Rightarrow)$  what can we do?

Any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not true. For example, take any nonzero complex with $d=0$. What is true is that $\text{id}_\mathcal{A}\sim0$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$  being split **and** acyclic.